# System.DllNotFoundException: libsqlite3_xamarin when connecting to SQLite database in Android 7+

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and trying to create an app. When I try to create a SQLite database in Android below 7 then it's working perfectly. But when I am trying to create a database in 7 and 7.1 then I get this error. For this problem, see this [link to the Xamarin discussion forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77732/sqlite-and-ndk-provided-native-libs) and I integrated the code:

```
 public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {

        var sqliteFilename = "ADB.db3";
        string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open("ATSDB.db3")))
            {
                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int length = 0;
                    while ((length = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        bw.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        // var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
        var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroidN();

        var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, path);
        // Return the database connection 
        return conn;

    }
```

**at this line I am getting Error ** `var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, path);
// Return the database connection`

**I am getting below error :**

```
{System.DllNotFoundException: libsqlite3_xamarin      
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroidNInternal:sqlite3_open_v2 (byte[],intptr&,int,intptr)

    at SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroidN.Open (System.Byte[] filename, SQLite.Net.Interop.IDbHandle& db, System.Int32 flags, System.IntPtr zvfs) [0x00000] in <360d65bfaa3e44c0b2b5840d827a452d>:0 

    at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor (SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, System.String databasePath, 
    SQLite.Net.Interop.SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks, SQLite.Net.IBlobSerializer serializer, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] tableMappings, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] extraTypeMappings, 
    SQLite.Net.IContractResolver resolver) [0x000a2] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 

    at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor (SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, System.String databasePath, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks, 
    SQLite.Net.IBlobSerializer serializer, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] tableMappings, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] 
    extraTypeMappings, SQLite.Net.IContractResolver resolver) [0x00000] 
    in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 
    at ATSDriver.Droid.SqliteService.GetConnection () [0x000b5] 
    in E:\Projects\DriverApp\Source\ATSDriver\ATSDriver\ATSDriver.Android\SqliteService.cs:52 

at ATSDriver.DataAccess..ctor () [0x00009] in E:\Projects\DriverApp\Source\ATSDriver\ATSDriver\ATSDriver\DataAccess.cs:17 }
```

Hope some one can help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 11):

In my case (targeting Android 9.0), I noticed that the Debug build worked, while the Release build did not. That's often a sign the [linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) is discarding too much. Adding `Mono.Data.Sqlite` to the 'Ignore assemblies' linker options did the trick for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with `Sqlite.Net` see a list of bugs about this [here](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20android%207) in particular [this one](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/329). Android restricted access to files after Android 7 and this affected the `Sqlite.Net` package

In short the package `Sqlite.Net` is dead as the owner has not updated it to work with Android 7. Ref: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/370

I suggest you switch to [Sqlite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) which supports Android 7+

Comment: thanks for your comments, is any example link for this for how can i use this because i have completed all the part of this app and in last i am getting such this very painful error

Comment: @A.Goutam Theres's no guide to doing this. its just a case of remove the old `Sqlite.Net` nuget package and install `Sqlite-Net` nuget package instead. Then build and fix any errors. Most of the errors will simply be changing a namespace. It's a pain but all users of `Sqlite.Net` have been there